# Form validation vs relying on foreign key contraints

Tags: php, mysql

I am using foreign key constraints in the database structure. At the same time, Im also validating the data that will be coming from the client side.

For example, when a user submits a form that contains a "customer" field and its primary key as value, I am going to check whether this customer exists before doing a database insert. Even though I have already set a foreign key constraint.

Is the method Im doing a bit redundant? Or is it REALLY redundant?

Comment: IMO this is fine. Don't let the user do something in the GUI that is not OK. And also define your DB with the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

It's not redundant, because you're serving two different purpouse:

- the client-side check is to improve user experience, and to tell the user what's wrong with what he has submitted; you can catch an error before it reaches the DB, and give him a proper error message, not a MySQL ugly one
- the server/DB-side check(s) are in place to protect your application, from errors or malicious behaviours (injection and so on)